# How to take back more than one values from function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

thanks in advance

am wondering how can i get many values from a code block..i dont know wiether i have to use array or anything...am new to js

consider the html code

```
 <div class="row">
            
            <div class=" available seat" data="C-08" ></div>
            <label>C-08</label>

            <div class=" available seat" data="D-08"></div>
            <label>D-08</label>

            <div class=" available seat" data="E-08"></div>
            <label >E-08</label>

            
        </div>
```

i need to get back seat numbers of each seats like......E08    FO8  ETC

What i did is

```
 let selectedSeats=document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.available'); 
   let seatNumber=[]
   selectedSeats.forEach((sts)=>{
          seatNumbers=[sts.nextElementSibling.innerText];
     });
console.log(seatNumbers);
```

am getting only last seat number on log

anybody please tell me how can i get all the seat numbers

Comment: You're overwriting `seatNumbers` in each pass of your `foreach` loop. Instead, push a value to the array: `seatNumbers.push([sts.nextElementSibling.innerText]);`

Comment: thanks..it worked.....when i did that am getting some value more than one time

Comment: You're not initialising the correct variable, it should be `let seatNumbers=[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array#Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to push text to your `seatNumber` array[].

Also **instead** of using `nextElementSibling` i would rec-emend using new [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) which are much `feasible` and easy to use.

Using data attributes will ensure you are getting exact data you want from the `div` and not **unwanted** *spaces or etc etc* from the `label`

**Edit:** Since you highlighted that you want to only push unique value and avoid duplicates for that you can use `IndexOf()` to check if the array contains the existing seat number. It will only only the unique seat numbers only.

**Live Demo:**

```js
let selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.available');
let seatNumber = []
selectedSeats.forEach((sts) => {
  let seats = sts.getAttribute('data') //get seat number
  if (seatNumber.indexOf(seats) === -1) {
    seatNumber.push(seats); //only push unique seats in to the array
  }
});
console.log(seatNumber);
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="available seat" data="C-08"></div>
  <label>C-08</label>

  <div class="available seat" data="A-02"></div>
  <label>A-02 - duplicate</label>

  <div class="available seat" data="D-08"></div>
  <label>D-08</label>

  <div class="available seat" data="A-02"></div>
  <label>A-02 - </label>

  <div class="available seat" data="E-08"></div>
  <label>E-08</label>

  <div class="available seat" data="E-08"></div>
  <label>E-08 duplicate</label>


</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much,,,i was not aware of data attribute.....and one problem is am getting values on console...but some values are repeating

that is when i click on three seats...am getting an array of 6 values

["A-02","A-02","E-06","F-01","A-02","E-06"]

actually it contain total 48 seats..its a movie ticket booking app   ... i need to output seat numbers on summary ..thats why

Comment: @kaki55 No worries. Happy to help. So you do not want any `duplication` of seat numbers in your array ? Meaning you do not want `A-02` and `A-02` to appear twice ?

Comment: yea...you are right..i dont wanna duplicate...its like when i click on one seat am getting one value on array....when clicking on two seats  its getting 3 values.....for 3 seats...am getting 6....and 10 for 4 seats....15 for 5 seats...it increase.....i just want excat seat numbrrs once...that is if a user choose 4 seats...i wanna output 4 seat numbers....

Comment: @kaki55 I have updated my answer. please check now. Its only pushing the unique seat number even though i have seat number appearing twice in my data.

Comment: gracias mucchisima gracias....it really worked perfect....awsome...i was thinking for last one day.....no idea....can you please explain how it worked..i didnt get that idea....that indexof and -1 statement..what actually it does ?

Comment: @kaki55 Sure! the way `indexOf` works is that on every loop it checks the `array` Data and checks if the seat number already exists. If it does not exist then it returns `-1` its pushes number to our array! and if the same seat number exist in the array it skips that seat without pushing that same number into out array. Here is more about how [Array#IndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) works - Happy coding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220066/discussion-between-kaki55-and-alwayshelping).

Answer (score 1):

Your forLoop is overriding each time it's being iterated.

You should try using the push() method as shown below:

```js
let selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll(".row .seat.available");
let seatNumber = [];
selectedSeats.forEach((sts) => {
  seatNumber.push(sts.nextElementSibling.innerText);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(seatNumber));
```

The console log with the parsed JSON results in this:

```
["C-08","D-08","E-08"]
```

Comment: Why `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use map from javascript to return an array. Example

```
const seatNumbers = selectedSeats.map(sts => sts.nextElementSibling.innerText);
```

This will return all the seat numbers in the same order of selected seats.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `push` instead of assigning to a new array

```js
let selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.available');
let seatNumbers = []
selectedSeats.forEach((sts) => {
  seatNumbers.push(sts.nextElementSibling.innerText);
});
console.log(seatNumbers);
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class=" available seat" data="C-08"></div>
  <label>C-08</label>

  <div class=" available seat" data="D-08"></div>
  <label>D-08</label>

  <div class=" available seat" data="E-08"></div>
  <label>E-08</label>


</div>
```